# node.js: HTTPS client certificate without server validation?

Tags: node.js, https, client-certificates

I have a https server and client in node.js.

For 'normal' HTTPS a host lets in any client, and the client authenticates the host.

However in my situation I would like to do the opposite:
I want the host to authenticate the client, but the client to connect to any host without authenticating it. ie: The host does not get a key/crt (but does trust the CA), while the client does gets a key/crt (and also trusts the CA).

The standard way for https with both sides authenticating each other is:
Server options:

```
key: fs.readFileSync('server-key.pem'), 
cert: fs.readFileSync('server-crt.pem'), 
ca: fs.readFileSync('ca-crt.pem'), 
requestCert: true, 
rejectUnauthorized: true
```

Client options:

```
key: fs.readFileSync('client-key.pem'), 
cert: fs.readFileSync('client-crt.pem'), 
ca: fs.readFileSync('ca-crt.pem') };
```

I removed key and crt from server, but how to tell the client not to request server/host cert? I can't seem to figure that part out? The documentation claims that for a client `rejectUnauthorized` must be set to true for the client to validate the server, so I set it to false. But the TLS handshake seems to be failing.

Comment: AFAIK, the SSL handshake is to first validate the server; if the server is validated by the client, and if the server is configured to request client certification, only then the server will request the client certificate and validate it. So a way to try it is to configure the server to request client certificates, but to not validate it. You would have to figure out the latter part...

Comment: Thanks that seems to work. I just give a the server a bogus cert with a working key for it, and the client doesn't care if rejectUnauthorized is false, meanwhile the server can still reject the cilent properly.